# Is there any way to implement MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack functionality in jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

ASP.NET 2.0 had the following property MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack and it could be used to maintain browser position on post back. Can this be achieved using jQuery and if yes how?
I have read a few articles mentioning that MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack doesnt work in some browsers like Chrome/Safari etc.

Answer (score 3):

Create an ASP hidden input field to store the position across postbacks, pass the ClientID of that field into the code below:

```
// client id of the hidden input field
var hiddenInputId = '<%= _myHiddenInputField.ClientID %>';

// store the current scroll position into the input
function storeScrollPosition(){
    $('#'+hiddenInputId)[0].value = scrollPosition();
}

// load the value out of the input and scroll the page
function loadScrollPosition(){
    var curPosition = $('#'+hiddenInputId)[0].value;
    if (curPosition > 0)
        $(window).scroll(curPosition);
}

// determine the scroll position (cross browser code)
function scrollPosition() {
    var n_result = window.pageYOffset ? 
                   window.pageYOffset : 0;
    var n_docel = document.documentElement ? 
                  document.documentElement.scrollTop : 0;
    var n_body = document.body ? 
                 document.body.scrollTop : 0;
    if (n_docel && (!n_result || (n_result > n_docel)))
        n_result = n_docel;
    return n_body && (!n_result || (n_result > n_body)) ? n_body : n_result;
}

// on load of the page, load the previous scroll position
$(document).ready(function(){loadScrollPosition();});
// on scroll of the page, update the input field
$(window).scroll(function(){storeScrollPosition();});
```

This will only work for postbacks. If you need to always have the same screen position we can play with cookies :)

Comment: I changed this line:  **$(window).scroll(curPosition);** 
  to use the **scrollTop** function, and this worked great.  Thanks!